# Why is writing to existing files slower than writing to nonexisting files?

Tags: c, performance, io, fwrite

Consider the following example code:

```
/* verify.c */
#include <stdio.h>

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if (argc < 2)
    return 0;

  char *filename = argv[1];

  FILE *f = fopen(filename, "w");
  if (!f)
    perror("something went wrong");

  // random data
  #define SIZE 65536
  #define ITER 1024
  unsigned int buffer[SIZE] = { 0 };

  unsigned int i;
  for (i = 0; i < ITER; ++i)
    {
      int res = fwrite(buffer, sizeof(*buffer), SIZE, f);
      if (res != SIZE)
        perror("something went wrong");
    }

  fclose(f);

  return 0;
}
```

Uninterestingly, his program will write <del>random</del> data to a file. 
Interestingly though, the program is orders of magnitude faster, if the file does not exist, although its contents are not at all relevant to the program.

```
time ./verify notexists

  real    0m0.162s
  user    0m0.000s
  sys     0m0.162s

time ./verify exists

  real    0m3.807s
  user    0m0.002s
  sys     0m0.268s
```

Why is that?

EDIT:
thanks to @rodrigo's suggestion below, I ran both cases throuh `strace`, and it reported that the `close` system call takes a long time to complete if the file exists.

if the file exists:

```
close(3)                                = 0 <2.673454>
```

otherwise:

```
close(3)                                = 0 <0.000011>
```

Comment: No difference on my system (OS X 10.9.5, HFS+ on an SSD). Possibly, as @rodrigo suggests, you're using a filesystem that's very slow at truncating files.

Comment: You say that `echo "" > file` does not take 3 seconds, but what about `rm file`?

Comment: @rodrigo `rm file` is instantaneous.

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin: Yeah, I just realized my comment was nonsense and deleted it :-(

Comment: @rodrigo no worries =)

Comment: Sounds like the system is waiting for the data to actually be flushed to disk before returning from `close` in the overwrite case, and only putting it in a write cache in the new-file case.

Comment: @AndrewMedico: Yes, I'm guessing that it is an issue with the free space managing in a SSD card. Maybe when the file exists the SSD sectors are deleted an reused. And deleting an SSD sector can be quite slow...

Comment: @AndrewMedico it seems you are right - `time sync` supports that.

Comment: Can you try the `noauto_da_alloc` mount option? Maybe that can improve the situation at the risk of data loss.

Comment: This is a benchmark with Undefined Behavior. Remove it. No need for it.

Comment: @usr care to elaborate on that? =)

Comment: You are using initialized memory. That makes the entire execution exhibit Undefined Behavior. You can never be sure that everything is correct.

Comment: @usr fixed. not that it changes anything in this case, but you are right.

Comment: Please, take a look at [Delayed allocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4#Delayed_allocation_and_potential_data_loss). I'm now pretty sure that this is the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the file does exist, `"w"` will truncate it, that is, remove all its contents. That takes time, possibly a lot of time is the file is very big and the file system is not very good (FAT?).

Opposed to that, when the file does not exist, it will be created, that is to add a directory entry and an inode or whatever the file system uses. But these structures are always small, so it is not a big deal.

Comment: it's a ext4. and I would expect truncating of a file to be in O(1), for example `echo "" > file` does not take several seconds if the file exists.

Comment: also, `touch file && ./verify file` takes about 3.8 seconds as well.

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin. That is weird... if you use linux can you run `strace -T ./verify exists` and tell what happens?

Comment: strace shows,  that a lot of time is spent in `close`, when the file exists. the write system calls return at about the same speed.

Comment: `close(3) = 0 <3.679479>` vs. `close(3) = 0 <0.000011>`

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin: Interesting... it is the `close()` that takes time not the `open()`. I'm expecting that all your existing and unexisting files are in the same directory, aren't they? Also, can you post your `mount` options?

Comment: yes they are. the relevant line in `mount` is `/dev/sda4 on /home type ext4 (rw,noatime)`

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin: I'm almost out of ideas... is it a SDD or a classid mechanical HD? Also, can you run `sync; time (rm file; sync)`?

Comment: it's a mechanical HDD. are you suggesting I should check its smart counters to see if it breaks? also, the time you wanted is `real 0m0.155s`

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin: Yes,  why not? checking that won't hurt. My last idea, how many files do you have in your directory? Sometimes ext4 can be inefficient if you have thousands of files in the same directory.

Comment: 4. =)             .............